# ¿Cómo agregar el atributo selected a la etiqueta option de un select?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, atributos

Quisiera saber como debería agregar el atributo 'selected' a la etiqueta 'option' de una lista. Estuve probando varias alternativas con 'jquery' o 'javascript' y no me ha salido, no sé en que me estaré confundiendo.

Dejo el código para que puedan decirme el error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        "url":"lib/gestion/paciente/procesar_provincias.php",
        "type":"post",
        "dataType":"json",
        "data":{'peticion': 'procesar_provincias'}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        //console.log(data.obraSocialPaciente.length);
        var nombreProvincia = $("#nombreProvincia").val();
        //console.log(nombreProvincia);
        $("#textProvincia option").remove();
        $("#textProvincia").append('<option value="0" name="0" class="">Seleccionar provincia</option>');
        for(var i = 0; i < data.provincias.length; i++){
            if(data.provincias[i].nombre == nombreProvincia){
                var id = data.provincias[i].id_provincia;
                console.log(id);
                $("#"+id).attr("selected:selected");
                //console.log(document.getElementByID(data.provincias[i].id_provincia+).value()+);
            }
            $("#textProvincia").append('<option id="'+data.provincias[i].id_provincia+'" value="'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'" >'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'</option>');
        }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error al cargar las provincias");
    }); 
});
```

La idea justamente es que la provincia con id = 23 quede seleccionada.

Agrego una imagen para que se entienda mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta usando attr("selected", "selected") en lugar de  attr("selected:selected")

Answer (score 0):

- Puedes agregar una variable que almacene el ID antes del ciclo For
- Despues dentro de tu ciclo For asignas el valor del ID que tienes en tu condición IF
- y fuera del ciclo For le puedes pasar a tu input Select #textProvincia el valor obtenido en los pasos anteriores

por ejemplo:

```js
var idItemSelectedValue = ""; // variable que espera el valor seleccionado para el input #textProvincia
$("#textProvincia").append('<option value="0" name="0" class="">Seleccionar provincia</option>');
    for(var i = 0; i < data.provincias.length; i++){
        if(data.provincias[i].nombre == nombreProvincia){
            var id = data.provincias[i].id_provincia;
            console.log(id);
            //$("#"+id).attr("selected:selected");
            idItemSelectedValue = data.provincias[i].nombre; // le asignamos a la variable idItemSelectedValue el valor tomado por los elementos option dentro de un form
 //console.log(document.getElementByID(data.provincias[i].id_provincia+).value()+);
        }
        $("#textProvincia").append('<option id="'+data.provincias[i].id_provincia+'" value="'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'" >'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'</option>');
    }
    
$("#textProvincia").val(idItemSelectedValue); // asignamos el valor de la variable idItemSelectedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer que espere la consulta

```js
    function lista(){
        return $.ajax({
              "url":"lib/gestion/paciente/procesar_provincias.php",
              "type":"post",
              "dataType":"json",
              "data":{'peticion': 'procesar_provincias'}
              }).done(function(data) {
                $("#textProvincia option").remove();
                $("#textProvincia").append('<option value="0" name="0" class="">Seleccionar provincia</option>');
                for(var i = 0; i < data.provincias.length; i++){        
                    $("#textProvincia").append('<option id="'+data.provincias[i].id_provincia+'" value="'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'" >'+data.provincias[i].nombre+'</option>');
                }
              })
              .fail(function() {
              alert("Error al cargar las provincias");
              }); 

    }
    async function data(){
         var nombreProvincia = $("#nombreProvincia").val();
         await lista();
         $("#textProvincia").val(nombreProvincia);
         //$("#"+id).val(23);
    }
```

y ahora solo debes invocarlo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    data();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Brevemente, ¿probaste con agregar a tu `attr` lo siguiente?

```
$("#"+id).attr("selected:selected").trigger("chosen:updated");
```